# IBM Db2 on Cloud: Results not shown in SQL editor

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I have uploaded the tables and created them in IBM Db2 on Cloud.
However, when I run queries in the SQL editor, the results are not being displayed.

[image: Screenshot]

So I am unable to verify if the results are correct.

How do I go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the arrow on the right. It will open a new window and display the result.

[image: show results]

Comment: Oh!!! It's just the arrow... i see the results now.... Thank you so much